# .Net Reflection Issue with Methods in NDoc Enhanced

Tags: .net, reflection, ndoc

I've used NDoc for quite a while now using a customised build (i.e. slightly bug-fixed build) of NDoc Enhanced (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc-e/) but I've run into a strange issue with methods that have parameters which themselves take generic parameters.

For example anything that has a Dictionary as a parameter where the type parameters for the dictionary are not base class types will not find documentation properly as when the code uses Type.FullName to get the type it gets a really long string like the following:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[VDS.RDF.INode, dotNetRDF, Version=0.2.0.26419, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82b4e01e1f8f2469],[VDS.RDF.INode, dotNetRDF, Version=0.2.0.26419, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82b4e01e1f8f2469]]
```

I assume there must be some way around this but I can't figure out what.  The really strange thing is that the Type with the above fullname will report itself as not being a GenericType or having GenericTypeParameters which seems completely wrong to me.  Does anyone know what the issue and corresponding workaround for this is?

I can switch to using NDoc3 instead which doesn't have this issue but that project doesn't publish it's source code so I can't look it up myself.

Can someone satisfy my curiosity and enlighten me?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but you might want to consider http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/

Comment: I tried using Sandcastle and really didn't like it